# how does accordion works?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not asking how to `show/hide` content upon `click`.

All I want to know is how by placing 2 divs, one on top the other, I can get the effect that by clicking on the bottom div, it "closing" the upper div. that's all. Not exactly accordion, but this is enough for my situation.

I tried to achieve this by animating the upper div height to 0, after clicking the bottom div. It works but not smoothly enough. and IE browsers didn't like it:

**JQUERY**

```
$('#BottomDiv').click(function() {    
    $('#UpperDiv').animate({ height: '0px' }, "slow");
});
```

in the markup side, both divs are position - relative:

**HTML**

```
  <div id="UpperDiv" style="height:190px; width:100%; margin-top:80px; position:relative">
  </div>
  <div id="BottomDiv" style="width:100%; position:relative; z-index:10; float:left;" >
  </div>
```

So I was just curious maybe there is a better way to achieve this, like jQuery accordion does it. Smooth and works for all browsers.

Comment: Show us how you did it, provide some code

Comment: what did you try the first time? Theres a Slide() function, and an Animate() function built into jQuery. I'd suggest Slide().

Comment: code added. i think that the "float:left" on the bottom div is what cause the animation to do not be "smooth", removing it really improve it but i really need it, since the original div contains data that need to be floated left.

Comment: for a "smooth" addition, you can play with the jquery ui effects core...here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/FBmFC/

Comment: sofl - in jsfiddle it works, not doubt. in reality - not so much. i wish i could show it to you on my develop enviroment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a structure such as:

```
<div id="accordionWrapper">
    <div id="UpperDiv" class="accordionSlides">
        <h2>Accordion tab</h2>
        <!-- other content, 'p' elements in the demo -->
    </div>

    <div id="MiddleDiv" class="accordionSlides">
        <h2>Accordion tab</h2>
        <!-- other content, 'p' elements in the demo -->
    </div>

    <div id="BottomDiv" class="accordionSlides">
        <h2>Accordion tab</h2>
        <!-- other content, 'p' elements in the demo -->
    </div>
</div>​
```

Then I'd suggest:

```
$('#accordionWrapper .accordionSlides').click(
    function(){
        var cur = $(this);
        cur.siblings().children().not('h2').slideUp(); // hides
        cur.find('p').slideToggle(); // shows
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xft79/1/).

References:

- [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).
- [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).
- [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).

Answer (score 1):

Does this help ?

**Markup:**

```
<div id="UpperDiv" style='background:red;height:200px;'>
</div>
<div id="BottomDiv" style="background:Gray;height:200px;">
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#BottomDiv').click(function() {    
    $('#UpperDiv').slideUp("slow","linear");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#BottomDiv').click(function() {    
    $('#UpperDiv').css("display", 'none');
});
```

The simple solution is above, however, more elegant would be to define a css class such as:

```
.invisible
{
    display: none;
}
```

and you can make something invisible by using the addClass function and you can remove this class by using removeClass from the tag to make it visible again.

Comment: Hiding is the easy part. i meant to the animation. "cover" it, maybe slide() will be better rather than animate().